# How do I change a SharePoint ClientSideWebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I have links in a SharePoint Online site page that I would like to retrieve and modify from within a C# application. I have been successful in using the SharePointPnPCoreOnline NuGet package to change links within a ClientSideText object, but I am stuck when I try to do the same with a ClientSideWebPart object. I can read the HTML (via the HtmlPropertiesData property) but I can't update it because it is a read-only property.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: I havent tried it, but can you use `GetPublicInstancePropertyValue` and `SetPublicInstancePropertyValue` method to get the HTML content and update the link and set it back?

Comment: I tried, but the SetPublicInstancePropertyValue method threw an exception "Property set method not found".

Comment: Is there another way to do what I am asking? ...possibly by not using the SharePoint PnP Core library?

Comment: Can you let me know, what you already have and what are trying to achieve using code? Maybe I can figure out another way or workaround.

Comment: See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using the following steps:

1. Get a JSON object from the ServerProcessedContent property.

```
JObject jsonObject = clientSideWebPart.ServerProcessedContent;
```

2. Update the object with my changes.

```
jsonObject[@"imageSources"][@"imageURL"] = imageSourcesImageUrl;
```

3. Set the PropertiesJson property to the JSON object's text (call ToString()).

```
string json = jsonObject.ToString();
clientSideWebPart.PropertiesJson = json;
```

These was certainly not intuitive. I had to read through the SharePointPnPCoreOnline library's code to understand what needed to be done.